# How to call a remote java program from google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, google-app-engine, google-chrome-extension

I have a working java program which have several jar files in its classpath. I need to generate a google chrome extension which takes input as browser URL and submits to remote java program. The output of java program is returned to extension. The extension displays the result to the user.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: too broad. show us your research, what you tried so far and what is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a server on Google Compute Engine and set up a webservice which will run the java program and return its output. It doesn't need to be Compute Engine but you'll have to run the java on a server somewhere and ad a webservice.

see Compute Engine at https://cloud.google.com/compute/

Here are some quickstart documents: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstarts

Comment: does not answer the question in extension context.

Comment: extensions are basically webapps so they can make a call to a webservice...

Comment: no, they need special permissions and other details (already answered in other questions). I marked it too broad because we dont even know if his issue is in making the extension and calls, or making the backend, or what he tried so far, what is failing etc.

Comment: so far, I have extracted the URL of browser through extension. And have executable java program. I am sorry to say this, i dont have any clue to connect the extension and java application. I would try the suggestion given by Serge hendrickz whether it works for me or not.